# Pandas filter for unique greater than 1 and concatenate the unique values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3],
                    'type':['m','n','o','m','m','n','n', 'p']})
```

And I would like to find which values of `c` have more than one unique type and for those return the `c` value, the number of unique types and all the unique types concatenated in one string.

I have used those two questions to get so far:

[pandas add column to groupby dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189878/pandas-add-column-to-groupby-dataframe)
[Python Pandas: concatenate rows with unique values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27174009/python-pandas-concatenate-rows-with-unique-values)

```
df2['Unique counts'] = df2.groupby('c')['type'].transform('nunique')

df2[df2['Unique counts'] > 1].groupby(['c', 'Unique counts']).\
                                  agg(lambda x: '-'.join(x))

Out[226]: 
                    type
c Unique counts         
1 3                m-n-o
2 2              m-m-n-n
```

This works but I cannot get the unique values (so for example in the second row I would like to have only one `m` and one `n`.
My questions would be the following:

1. Can I skip the in between step for creating the 'Unique counts' and
   create something temporary?
2. How can I filter for only unique values
   in the second step?

Comment: Order is important in output?

Comment: Not really. I just want the unique ones per group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for remove unique rows first and then count values - create helper Series `s` and for unique strings is used `set`s:

```
s= df2.groupby('c')['type'].transform('nunique').rename('Unique counts')
a = df2[s > 1].groupby(['c', s]).agg(lambda x: '-'.join(set(x)))
print (a)

                  type
c Unique counts       
1 3              o-m-n
2 2                m-n
```

Another idea is removing duplicates first by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df3 = df2[df2.duplicated(['c'],keep=False) & ~df2.duplicated(['c','type'])]
print (df3)

   c type
0  1    m
1  1    n
2  1    o
3  2    m
5  2    n
```

And then aggregate counts with join:

```
a = df3.groupby('c')['type'].agg([('Unique Counts', 'size'), ('Type', '-'.join)])
print (a)
   Unique Counts   Type
c                      
1              3  m-n-o
2              2    m-n
```

---

Or if need all values aggregate first:

```
df4 = df2.groupby('c')['type'].agg([('Unique Counts', 'nunique'), 
                                  ('Type', lambda x: '-'.join(set(x)))])
print (df4)
   Unique Counts   Type
c                      
1              3  o-m-n
2              2    m-n
3              1      p
```

And last remove unique rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df5 = df4[df4['Unique Counts'] > 1]
print (df5)
   Unique Counts   Type
c                      
1              3  o-m-n
2              2    m-n
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works! I am new in Python and I come from R so I have the following questions: Is it possible to skip the in-between assignment to s and how does set work?

Comment: @User2321 - i thin yes if change another solution.

Comment: @User2321 - set is an unordered collection of items. For more information is possible check [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/set)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) and pass `tuple`'s of `(column name, function)`:

```
df2.groupby('c')['type'].agg([('Unique Counts', 'nunique'), ('Type', lambda x: '-'.join(x.unique()))])
```

[out]

```
   Unique Counts   Type
c                      
1              3  m-n-o
2              2    m-n
3              1      p
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) and filter on `Unique counts` column as you want:

```
df2 = (df2.groupby('c', as_index=False)
          .agg({'type': ['nunique', lambda x: '-'.join(np.unique(x))]}))
df2.columns = ['c','Unique counts','type']

print(df2)
   c  Unique counts   type
0  1              3  m-n-o
1  2              2    m-n
2  3              1      p
```

Filtering on `Unique counts`:

```
df2 = df2.loc[df2['Unique counts']>1,:]

print(df2)
   c  Unique counts   type
0  1              3  m-n-o
1  2              2    m-n
```